# PHP Exchange Web Services - get message body

Tags: php, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm using a [PHP EWS](https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews/) library, and took [this example](https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews/wiki/Email-%3a-Get-List) to get a list of messages, which works perfectly.

It pulls through details such as the sender, receiver, subject, time etc. I tried looking through all the library, but I can't workout how to pull through the message body and attachments.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is well described in PHP EWS wiki, right here: https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews/wiki/Email-:-Retrieve-All-Email-Attachments

Edit: use whole example linked above to fetch email attachments and just part of it to get the message:

```
$message_id = ''; // Id of the email message

$ews = new ExchangeWebServices($host,  $user, $password);

$request = new EWSType_GetItemType();

$request->ItemShape = new EWSType_ItemResponseShapeType();
$request->ItemShape->BaseShape = EWSType_DefaultShapeNamesType::ALL_PROPERTIES;

$request->ItemIds = new EWSType_NonEmptyArrayOfBaseItemIdsType();
$request->ItemIds->ItemId = new EWSType_ItemIdType();
$request->ItemIds->ItemId->Id = $message_id; 

$response = $ews->GetItem($request);

if( $response->ResponseMessages->GetItemResponseMessage->ResponseCode == 'NoError' &&
    $response->ResponseMessages->GetItemResponseMessage->ResponseClass == 'Success' ) {

    $message = $response->ResponseMessages->GetItemResponseMessage->Items->Message;
}
```

At this point you have the `$message`. To access body  use `$message->body` - it's an object with bodyType etc - to actually read the message body content use `$message->body->_`

Comment: Yes thanks i saw that, but it doesn't help with getting the message body unfortunately.

Comment: Hi, I am having the same problem of fetching the email body.. i tried the above code but it dsnt work for me.. the $message variable turns out to be empty...  I have posted the issue along with the code here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300863/php-and-exchange-web-services-fetching-the-message-body-using-php-ews

Comment: Replied in your question, also all the information you needed is here in my answer, just below sample code.

Comment: I have updated my code. I am getting a fully formed $message object now. Previously I had missed the "RootFolder" attribute. However the $message object does not contain a "body" attribute. Please check my update to view the print_r() output of the $message variable.